# I want to redirect to another page if a condition in javascript is true

Tags: javascript, html, air

I am developing a desktop app with Adobe AIR. I want to redirect to another page if internet connection is present, and do nothing if internet connection is not present.

Following is the code I am using for detecting internet connection. The following code displays "Please wait" if internet connection is present, and "Internet connection is unavailable" if internet is not connected.

`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function CheckOnlineStatus(msg) {
            var status = document.getElementById("status");
            var condition = navigator.onLine ? "Please wait" : "Internet connection is unavailable"; 
            var state = document.getElementById("state");
            state.innerHTML = condition;
        }

        function Pageloaded() {
           CheckOnlineStatus("load");
           document.body.addEventListener("offline", function () {
           CheckOnlineStatus("offline")
           }, false);
           document.body.addEventListener("online", function () {
           CheckOnlineStatus("online")
           }, false);
        }

    </script>
    <style>
        ...</style>
</head>
<body onload="Pageloaded()">
    <div id="status">
        <p id="state">
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Please suggest required additions or changes to redirect to "http://example.com" if `navigator.onLine` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(navigator.onLine){
     window.location.href = "http://example.com";
}
```

window.location is an object which exists as a property of window. href is a property of window.location which indicates the URL of your current page. You can redirect by assigning a URL to window.location.href.

Comment: How can I add a time delay for redirection? (I am a bit low in javascript)

Comment: You can use the setTimeout method. Use `setTimeout(someFunction, 1000)`. 1000 is the time in milliseconds. (1000 milliseconds is one second)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "http://example.com";
```

Use that to redirect.

Comment: Where online did you find the snippet you posted originally?